# How to center text in a small section of art board in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

I have a text I wish to center, but rather than the whole art board, I want to center it to the half of the art board. That is to say I have split the art board in two, and I wish to center the text in one of these halves.

Is this possible with a click or a setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the text box and after check **Align to Artboard** from the top panel options

[image: Align to Artboard]

- Center it vertically and horizontally
- Activate the transform **Middle Reference Point** [image: reference point]
- Put the cursor behind the **Y** value and add <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (divided 2) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to place it in the middle of the top half

Other values from the center:

- Put the cursor behind the **Y** value and add <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (multiplied by 2) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to place it in the middle of the lower half
- Put the cursor behind the **X** value and add <kbd>/</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (divided 2) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to place it in the middle of the left half
- Put the cursor behind the **X** value and add <kbd>*</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> (multiplied by 2) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to place it in the middle of the right half

[image: align]

Comment: O wow, this is something I wish I knew a long time ago. This is very useful!

Comment: @AndrewH you can do simple mathematical operations ( + – * / ) in each numerical field of Illustrator and Indesign